# jupyter notebook: nbconvert notebook charset-normalizer failed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main::charset-normalizer-2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. D:\Anaconda__python\Scripts\conda.exe
Attempting to roll back.

CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. D:\Anaconda__python\Scripts\conda.exe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.